# Change captured image resolution in Android?

Tags: android, camera

How can i change resolution of captured image base on below configuration

The extraction coordinates would be x = 710, y = 1880 (upper left corner) and x = 2410, y = 2280 (lower right corner). This would get the centered 1700x400 rectangle's image area.

Comment: Bitmap,rescaleBitmap

Comment: BUt how it work for coordinates

Comment: I do not understand